# Disable select box and enable textbox using one checkbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm am fairly new to JavaScript; I have been googling all day for this but i only found how to enable and disable one textbox using one checkbox.

#### Here is my code

JavaScript

```
 function enable_text(status){
     status=!status;    
     document.sr2.other_text.disabled = status;
 }
```

HTML

```
<form name=sr2 method=post>
    <input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this.checked)">
    Others
    <input type=text name=other_text>
</form>
```

Note: the code I posted is only for a textbox that when uncheck in checkbox it will be enabled.

My question is how do you disable select tag and enable a textbox after unchecking a checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to your text box then just put the below `onclick` of your checkbox instead of the function call.

```
 <form name=sr2 method=post>
 <input type="checkbox" name=others onclick= "document.getElementById('id_of_txtbox').disabled=this.checked;">Others
 <input type=text name=other_text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, are you trying to present a dropdown but then allow them to enter other values not in the dropdown?

If so, here is another way to approach it:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="RenewalTerm" id="RenewalTerm">
    <option value="12">12 Month</option>
    <option value="24">24 Month</option>
    <option value="36">36 Month</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<span id="RenewalTermOtherFields">
    <label labelfor="RenewalTermManual" >Enter Renewal Term: </label>
    <input type="text" name="RenewalTermManual" id="RenewalTermManual" />
</span>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#RenewalTermOtherFields').hide();
    $('#RenewalTermManual').val($('#RenewalTerm').val());
    $('#RenewalTerm').change(function() {
        var selectedItem = $("select option:selected").val();
        if (selectedItem !== 'Other') {
            $('#RenewalTermOtherFields').hide();
            $('#RenewalTermManual').val($('#RenewalTerm').val());
        }
        else
        {
            $('#RenewalTermManual').val('');
            $('#RenewalTermOtherFields').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**See It In Action!:** http://eat-sleep-code.com/#/javascript/dropdown-with-other-field

This will allow you to select "other" from the list, and when you do it will automatically display a textbox for free-form entry.

Comment: @mohit actually both answer suffice i tried both and they gave me the ouput i want thank you very much guys!

Comment: @eat-sleep-code id love to put a vote up on your answer but i dont have sufficient reputation to do so

Answer (score 0):

Here's the HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txt" disabled="disabled"/>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" onclick="enableText(this.checked)">Uncheck to Disable Select and Enable Text
```

And the JavaScript is

```
function enableText(checked){
    if(!checked){
        document.getElementById('sel').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('txt').disabled = false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('sel').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('txt').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Select is disabled and text is enabled on uncheking the checkbox and vice versa. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: i tried your code and this one also works, wow didnt know there are a lot of approaches to my question; id love to vote up your answer but unfortunately i dont have enough reputation to do that but your answer is highly accepted to :)

Comment: i have a question on your code what if there are two selects and two textbox having id's sel1 and sel2 and tx1 and txt2 would it be possible to re-use your code for that? i have been doing some experiments and it seems that your code does not work if there are already two selects and two txtboxes involve; i change their id's (which i did to check functionality) but it does not work; i know your code will be helpful in the future so i'd be happy to know if you know a fix for that

Comment: It should work no matter how many select or text boxes are there. Can you post the code you are trying?

Comment: all good now here is the code i have generated.

     <script>
     function enableText(checked, index){
          var sel = true, txt = false;

          if(checked) {
              sel = false;
              txt = true;
          }

          document.getElementById('sel' + index).disabled = sel;
          document.getElementById('txt' + index).disabled = txt;
     }

     window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('txt1').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('txt2').disabled = true;
     };
     </script>